# Are Favorite Answers being planned?

Tags: feature-request, answers, reputation, bookmarks

Sometimes, there's a question that gets posted. You have that problem, as well, so you take a look at the answers.

Now, let's say that the answer was the most awesome, well-written answer ever, and it offered multiple workarounds and solutions (you get the idea,) but the question was just.. marginally good.

So.. you want to favorite the answer, but the asker wasn't really deserving of the mound of Rep that a Favorite provides.

What do you do then?

I kind of feel like a jerk just upvoting, then walking away, but I also think that it's a little out-of-place to leave a "Thanks!" comment.

I propose the ability to Favorite an answer.
Please tell me what you think!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any answers that you think are the '*most awesome, well-written answer ever*' could do with a [bounty](https://askubuntu.com/privileges/set-bounties). You'll even get a couple of extra badges for your trouble.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Having a question marked as a favorite doesn't earn the asker any reputation, so that doesn't really matter.

If you upvote the answer you prefer every time you visit the page the arrow will be filled in, so you know that's the one you upvoted, poor man's favorite I guess.

Also if the answer is useful then clearly the question has merit, if the post is of poor quality then fix it by submitting edits to it.

Comment: "*...* if the answer is useful then clearly the question has merit *...*" Yes, it has merit on the basis that it produced a great answer, but sometimes, [that's the extent of its merit](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/).